# Show ProgressDialog While populating Realm db

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, progressdialog

I am Shipping Realm db with app and populating db on firstrun
Problem i am stuck with is if i am running Dialog and populating  as Asyn task or in a new thread
Then when i am instantiating realm db as

```
realm = realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

technically it should be run after population of database is finished as a result i am getting error

> Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.

Code used for populating db is

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                        .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                        .migration(new in.webic.longevity.longevity.Word())
                        .assetFile(context, "Default.realm")
                        .schemaVersion(0)
                        .build();
                realm = realm.getInstance(config);
                realm.close();
```

while this code is runs a blank screen appears i want it to be substituted by ProgressDialog or similar

am using this code but everything else should be run after population of db is finished which i am not able to achieve

```
 if (isFirstRun)
    {
 new Thread() 
           {
 public void run() 
           {
     try
               {

 RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                    .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                    .migration(new in.webic.longevity.longevity.Word())
                    .assetFile(context, "Default.realm")
                    .schemaVersion(0)
                    .build();
            realm = realm.getInstance(config);
            realm.close();

      }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag",e.getMessage());
    }
// dismiss the progressdialog   
  progressDialog.dismiss();
 }
}.start();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

I am not able to find how to populate db while showing dialogbox synchronously 
please help any snippet or hint will be helpful
Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce please help @epicpandaforce

Comment: Well for whatever reason I did **not** get that notification, but hey I got here eventually anyways

Comment: Just use the same `config` object, maybe make it final or static somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.

You're getting this error if `equals()` does not match for the two configurations. Which happens most likely because your Migration object's hashCode and equals are not re-defined.

```
public class Word extends Migration {
    //...migration

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return Word.class.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       return obj != null && obj instanceof Word;
    }
}
```

(or just use the same configuration instance)

Comment: I know why i am getting this error because when i try to run confugiration in a separate thread  `realm = realm.getDefaultInstance();` has been already completed synchrnously

Comment: i need a checkpoint in the code so rest of the lines in the code only runs if the thread is finished

Comment: I'd totally just use an event bus for this on a splash screen